# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Customer is not mapped [from Customer]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Customer is not
>   mapped [from Customer]

while everything is fine why it is showing this error

Bean class:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


//@Table(schema = "web_customer_tracker", name = "customer")
@Table(name="customer")
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Customer() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

DAO Impl class:

```
    package com.luv2code.springdemo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;

@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {

        //get the current hibernate session
            Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();


        //List customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        //create a query
        Query<Customer> theQuery=currentSession.createQuery("from customer", Customer.class);
                //currentSession.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class);
        //execute query and get result list
        List<Customer> customers=theQuery.getResultList();
        // return the results


        /*  Customer cus1=new Customer();
        cus1.setEmail("a@gmail.com");
        cus1.setFirstName("Abhishek");
        cus1.setId(10);
        cus1.setLastName("Kumar");
        customers.add(cus1); */

        return customers;
    }

}
```

[DATABASE:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XICmZ.png)

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="springstudent" />
        <property name="password" value="springstudent" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  
    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />


</beans>
```

Comment: do we have a hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: Try to set the schema `@Table(schema = "web_customer_tracker", name = "customer")`

Comment: Which version of Hibernate / JPA are you using in your project?

Comment: @lakshman Xml attached in question (Edited)

Comment: @MWiesner Hibernate 5.3.2 and Spring 5.0.7

Comment: try hql syntax query = '' select c from customer c ".

Comment: @HAYMbl4 used but same error is coming

Comment: @AngadBansode still same error is coming :
Customer is not mapped [Select c from Customer c]

Comment: i think you add wrong package name in your xml, change `com.` to `code.`

Comment: Customer table is created by hibernate or you manually?

Comment: @benjaminc where are you telling "To definr database datasource"?

Comment: @AngadBansode manually

Comment: why you created manually?. You added @Entity annotation then hibernate should create Customer table right? did you try to do hibernate create table itself?

Comment: @AngadBansode nothing like that is different concept

Comment: @ABHISHEKKUMAR no in `sessionFactory`

Comment: @benjaminc  in xml same package name is there

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are giving entity name in your Customer Entity,thus, same should be used in your queries(now name of the class cannot be referred in your queries). Try invoking the query with the same entity name mentioned(take care of cases as well).

Try as follows:

```
  Query<Customer> theQuery=
            currentSession.createQuery("from customer", Customer.class);
```

Here I have matched the entity name mentioned in `@Entity(name="customer")` in your query.

Comment: i make following changes still same error is coming:
@Entity(name="customer")
//@Table(schema = "web_customer_tracker", name = "customer")
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

Query<Customer> theQuery=currentSession.createQuery("from customer", Customer.class);

Error :
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: customer is not mapped [from customer]

Answer (score 0):

I didnt go through all your code but, in `sessionFactory` bean of `xml`,

Try changing `<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />` to `<property name="packagesToScan" value="code.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />`.

Your actual `Customer` entity lives in package `code.luv2code.springdemo.entity`
, though you have used `com.luv2code.springdemo.entity`. So it is scanning wrong package. This might be the problem.

Comment: no @benjamin i checked the package name both are same "com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" and also if i am giving hard coding in DAOImpl it is giving proper result;

Comment: @ABHISHEKKUMAR `Customer` entity is in `code.luv2code.springdemo.entity` right ?

Comment: @ABHISHEKKUMAR check package declaration of `Customer` class and import statement of `CustomerDAOImpl`. it comes from `code.luv2code.springdemo.entity` in provided code.

Comment: See i have changed the package name still same error is coming .See the edited class code

Comment: @ABHISHEKKUMAR try changing `from customer` to `from Customer`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using check if the packages of C3p0 of correct for hibernate, Iam using the following and it works for me.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.26.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also in contrast to the above answers, In Hibernate it is always the entity name for HQL even though you have added @Table(name="customer")

```
 Query<Customer> theQuery=
        currentSession.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class);
```

Let me know if this still does not work for you

Answer (score 0):

In `Customer` class

@Entity --> hibernate takes by Default as `@Entity(name = "Customer")`
though your database table is `customer` it reads as `Customer` because annotated class hibernate configures as `Customer`

so update,

```java
List<Customer> li = session.createQuery("from Customer").list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

Query theQuery=currentSession.createQuery("from Customer");